# Unable to run CMD in 64 bit mode on Win 7 Prof

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, cmd

I have done my homework, honest, and tried everything I can think of but it seems that every time I open CMD I get the 32bit version, regardless of where I open it from. I have tried:

1. Windows start orb -> CMD -> enter
2. Typing 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe'
3. Typing 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe'

In each case I am running it with Admin rights and I have UAC turned off. I can tell it's always 32 bit as I am unable in any case to run nbstat.exe (which I would expect from a 32 bit command line).

I have been into Process Explorer and both version are nodes under the same instance of csrss.exe which doesn't feel right to me.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to see if a process launches 64- or 32-bit is to go to the process tab of the task manager, a 32 bit CMD will show as `cmd.exe *32`.

One way to launch a 64-bit CMD is to just use "My Computer" and double click `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`.

One way to launch a 32-bit CMD is to do the same but double click `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`.

Slightly odd observation; it seems that if you launch the 64-bit CMD from a 32-bit one, it will also launch as 32-bit. That may be why you're seeing the 32-bit version show up all the time. Explorer is a 64-bit process and can launch CMD in 64-bit mode.

Comment: If you double-click on `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` you get a 32 bit shell, not 64. Double-click on `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` is 32 bit shell, not 64.  Just execute python and watch the message. It always says [..] on win32, meaning that the process shell on which python is running is win32

Comment: @Echeban that is completely wrong. Python says the version is win32 no matter what version of python or of Windows, it just means any version of windows, 32- or 64-bit.

Answer (score 3):

The version of command prompt that windows spawns matches the bit-ness of the launching process, via the magic of windows path redirection. Therefore, a command prompt started from a 32-bit program will be a 32-bit command prompt, and one started from a 64-bit application a 64-bit command prompt - [Microsoft Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26681.open-64-bit-command-prompt-in-32-bit-command-prompt-to-execute-64-bit-command-prompt-through-sccm.aspx).

The [technet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26681.open-64-bit-command-prompt-in-32-bit-command-prompt-to-execute-64-bit-command-prompt-through-sccm.aspx) suggests creating a symlink to the 64-bit version of the command prompt executable to defeat the redirect.

Reading the comments reveals that [an easier method exists](https://www.samlogic.net/articles/sysnative-folder-64-bit-windows.htm) (not Win XP), you can use the virtual folder C:\Windows\Sysnative to get the native versions of the system tools.

Therefore, to always get a 64-bit command prompt on 64-bit windows, execute:

```
C:\Windows\sysnative\cmd.exe
```