# Why does the same command work differently from CMD vs Process.Start()?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cmd, windows-10

The following command used in CMD or Win+R opens the screensaver dialog:

```
control desk.cpl,screensaver,@screensaver
```

The following does a similar thing, but most screensavers are missing from the drop-down (Only **(None)**, **Blank**, and **Photos** available):

```
Process.Start("control.exe", "desk.cpl,screensaver,@screensaver");
```

Why?

(And, obviously, how can I get the CMD result using C#/.Net?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in the bitness of the launching application. 64-bit explorer launching 64-bit control panel gets the full list.

An application running as 32-bit launches 32-bit control panel and gets the truncated list. And the same application running as 64-bit gets the full list again.

So the "obvious" fix is to change your project's properties to build for x64.

Comment: Works like a charm. (The project was building for AnyCPU.) Unfortunately my real application is built under AnyCPU and I'm not sure I'll be able to change that. Is there any way to launch the correct bitness (depending on the machine) from a 32 bit application?

Comment: OK. I think I found the answer [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61042207/939213) - to use `C:\Windows\sysnative\cmd.exe`.

Comment: @ispiro The differences between x86 and x64 applications running on Windows x64  is explained by the Microsoft documentation pages [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details), [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) and [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys). Every Windows programmer should be aware of these three documentation pages.

Comment: @ispiro The solution is not running `C:\Windows\sysnative\cmd.exe` on 64-Bit Windows by your 32-bit application, but running directly `C:\Windows\Sysnative\control.exe`. There is really no need to use C# [Process Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) which uses the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) and structure [STARTUPINFO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa) to ...

Comment: @ispiro start 64-bit `cmd.exe` from within a 32-bit executable which searches for `control.exe` and finds it hopefully first in `%SystemRoot%\System32` via environment variable `PATH` which is started next by the Windows command processor using `CreateProcess` and `STARTUPINFO`. So the usage of `cmd.exe` is a completely useless roundabout route to start 64-bit `control.exe` on Windows x64 and 32-bit `control.exe` on  Windows x86. And please don't use hard coded `C:\Windows`, use [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder).

Comment: @ispiro See also [How can redirection disabled on Windows 64?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17487922) as an alternative solution to disable temporarily the file system (and registry) redirections on starting `control.exe` in native Windows system directory using `Process` class.